# R - List to Data Frame to CSV file

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe

Maybe I am missing something and this is trivial, if so I apologize. I've tried a number of different methods each resulting in its own unique problems.

I have a list of MIXED data.  Numeric, Boolean, String, etc.  Some columns are Boolean.  Some are numeric.  Some are strings.

It's 3 rows, 24 columns.

Here's a simple example with less of each, but will demo what I want.

```
    name    boolVal    quote                              postNum
    Tom     TRUE       Howdy everyone!                    1337
    Tom     FALSE      Twitter is fun!                    1338
    Dara    FALSE      When it actually works lol.        24
```

So this is stored as variable "allMentions"
typeof(allMentions) returns "list"
dim(allMentions) returns 3 24, but in this toy example would be 3 4

I want to not lose my data types if possible...and I want to save this list to a CSV file.

To do that, I need to convert it to a data frame.

What is the "best" way to preserve my data and be able to save this to a .csv file for later analysis?

EDIT 1 : Was asked for str(allMentions)

```
  'data.frame':   3 obs. of  24 variables:
   $ metadata                 :'data.frame':      3 obs. of  2 variables:
    ..$ iso_language_code: chr  "en" "en" "en"
    ..$ result_type      : chr  "recent" "recent" "recent"
   $ created_at               : chr  "Thu Oct 22 01:19:44 +0000 2015" "Thu        Oct 22 01:15:46 +0000 2015" "Wed Oct 21 20:01:57 +0000 2015"
    $ id                       : num  6.57e+17 6.57e+17 6.57e+17
    etc with the rest of my variables and values


'data.frame':   3 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ metadata                 :'data.frame':      3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ iso_language_code: chr  "en" "en" "en"
  ..$ result_type      : chr  "recent" "recent" "recent"
 $ created_at               : chr  "Thu Oct 22 01:19:44 +0000 2015" "Thu Oct 22 01:15:46 +0000 2015" "Wed Oct 21 20:01:57 +0000 2015"
 $ id                       : num  6.57e+17 6.57e+17 6.57e+17
 $ id_str                   : chr  "657003367575760896" "657002373307568129" "656923397985816576"
 $ text                     : chr  "@esorarad It worked, in case youre curious, since I keep bothering you." "@esorarad still testing!!" "@esorarad Hey Dara! Tweeting at you so I can test a program I'm making :P Hopeful game night in the near future!"
 $ source                   : chr  "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>" "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>" "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"
 $ truncated                : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ in_reply_to_status_id    : logi  NA NA NA
 $ in_reply_to_status_id_str: logi  NA NA NA
 $ in_reply_to_user_id      : num  1.51e+09 1.51e+09 1.51e+09
 $ in_reply_to_user_id_str  : chr  "1512420228" "1512420228" "1512420228"
 $ in_reply_to_screen_name  : chr  "esorarad" "esorarad" "esorarad"
 $ user                     :'data.frame':      3 obs. of  40 variables:
  ..$ id                                : num  75328338 75328338 75328338
  ..$ id_str                            : chr  "75328338" "75328338" "75328338"
  ..$ name                              : chr  "Thomas" "Thomas" "Thomas"
  ..$ screen_name                       : chr  "uName" "uName" "uName"
  ..$ location                          : chr  "Philadelphia PA" "Philadelphia PA" "Philadelphia PA"
  ..$ description                       : chr  "" "" ""
  ..$ url                               : logi  NA NA NA
  ..$ entities                          :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ description:'data.frame':      3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. ..$ urls:List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ : list()
  .. .. .. ..$ : list()
  .. .. .. ..$ : list()
  ..$ protected                         : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ followers_count                   : num  36 36 36
  ..$ friends_count                     : num  244 244 244
  ..$ listed_count                      : num  1 1 1
  ..$ created_at                        : chr  "Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009" "Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009" "Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009"
  ..$ favourites_count                  : num  121 121 121
  ..$ utc_offset                        : num  -18000 -18000 -18000
  ..$ time_zone                         : chr  "Quito" "Quito" "Quito"
  ..$ geo_enabled                       : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ verified                          : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ statuses_count                    : num  616 616 616
  ..$ lang                              : chr  "en" "en" "en"
  ..$ contributors_enabled              : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ is_translator                     : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ is_translation_enabled            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ profile_background_color          : chr  "C0DEED" "C0DEED" "C0DEED"
  ..$ profile_background_image_url      : chr  "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png"
  ..$ profile_background_image_url_https: chr  "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png"
  ..$ profile_background_tile           : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ profile_image_url                 : chr  "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg" "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg" "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg"
  ..$ profile_image_url_https           : chr  "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg" "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg" "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg"
  ..$ profile_link_color                : chr  "0084B4" "0084B4" "0084B4"
  ..$ profile_sidebar_border_color      : chr  "C0DEED" "C0DEED" "C0DEED"
  ..$ profile_sidebar_fill_color        : chr  "DDEEF6" "DDEEF6" "DDEEF6"
  ..$ profile_text_color                : chr  "333333" "333333" "333333"
  ..$ profile_use_background_image      : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE
  ..$ has_extended_profile              : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ default_profile                   : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE
  ..$ default_profile_image             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ following                         : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ follow_request_sent               : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ notifications                     : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ geo                      : logi  NA NA NA
 $ coordinates              : logi  NA NA NA
 $ place                    : logi  NA NA NA
 $ contributors             : logi  NA NA NA
 $ is_quote_status          : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ retweet_count            : num  0 0 0
 $ favorite_count           : num  0 0 0
 $ entities                 :'data.frame':      3 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ hashtags     :List of 3
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  ..$ symbols      :List of 3
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  ..$ user_mentions:List of 3
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. ..$ screen_name: chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ name       : chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ id         : num 1.51e+09
  .. .. ..$ id_str     : chr "1512420228"
  .. .. ..$ indices    :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ : num  0 9
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. ..$ screen_name: chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ name       : chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ id         : num 1.51e+09
  .. .. ..$ id_str     : chr "1512420228"
  .. .. ..$ indices    :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ : num  0 9
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. ..$ screen_name: chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ name       : chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ id         : num 1.51e+09
  .. .. ..$ id_str     : chr "1512420228"
  .. .. ..$ indices    :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ : num  0 9
  ..$ urls         :List of 3
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
 $ favorited                : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ retweeted                : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ lang                     : chr  "en" "en" "en"
```

Next...

```
dput(droplevels(head(allMentions)))
    structure(list(metadata = structure(list(iso_language_code = c("en", 
    "en", "en"), result_type = c("recent", "recent", "recent")), .Names = c("iso_language_code", 
    "result_type"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame"), 
        created_at = c("Thu Oct 22 01:19:44 +0000 2015", "Thu Oct 22 01:15:46 +0000 2015", 
        "Wed Oct 21 20:01:57 +0000 2015"), id = c(657003367575761024, 
        657002373307568000, 656923397985816960), id_str = c("657003367575760896", 
        "657002373307568129", "656923397985816576"), text = c("@esorarad It worked, in case youre curious, since I keep bothering you.", 
        "@esorarad still testing!!", "@esorarad Hey Dara! Tweeting at you so I can test a program I'm making :P Hopeful game night in the near future!"
        ), source = c("<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", 
        "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>", 
        "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"
        ), truncated = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), in_reply_to_status_id = c(NA, 
        NA, NA), in_reply_to_status_id_str = c(NA, NA, NA), in_reply_to_user_id = c(1512420228, 
        1512420228, 1512420228), in_reply_to_user_id_str = c("1512420228", 
        "1512420228", "1512420228"), in_reply_to_screen_name = c("esorarad", 
        "esorarad", "esorarad"), user = structure(list(id = c(75328338, 
        75328338, 75328338), id_str = c("75328338", "75328338", "75328338"
        ), name = c("Thomas", "Thomas", "Thomas"
        ), screen_name = c("uName", "uName", "uName"), location = c("Philadelphia PA", 
        "Philadelphia PA", "Philadelphia PA"), description = c("", 
        "", ""), url = c(NA, NA, NA), entities = structure(list(description = structure(list(
            urls = list(list(), list(), list())), .Names = "urls", row.names = c(NA, 
        3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "description", row.names = c(NA, 
        3L), class = "data.frame"), protected = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
        ), followers_count = c(36, 36, 36), friends_count = c(244, 
        244, 244), listed_count = c(1, 1, 1), created_at = c("Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009", 
        "Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009", "Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009"
        ), favourites_count = c(121, 121, 121), utc_offset = c(-18000, 
        -18000, -18000), time_zone = c("Quito", "Quito", "Quito"), 
            geo_enabled = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), verified = c(FALSE, 
            FALSE, FALSE), statuses_count = c(616, 616, 616), lang = c("en", 
            "en", "en"), contributors_enabled = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
            ), is_translator = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), is_translation_enabled = c(FALSE, 
            FALSE, FALSE), profile_background_color = c("C0DEED", 
            "C0DEED", "C0DEED"), profile_background_image_url = c("http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
            "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png"
            ), profile_background_image_url_https = c("https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
            "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
            "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png"), 
            profile_background_tile = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), profile_image_url = c("http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg", 
            "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg", 
            "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg"
            ), profile_image_url_https = c("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg", 
            "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg", 
            "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg"
            ), profile_link_color = c("0084B4", "0084B4", "0084B4"
            ), profile_sidebar_border_color = c("C0DEED", "C0DEED", 
            "C0DEED"), profile_sidebar_fill_color = c("DDEEF6", "DDEEF6", 
            "DDEEF6"), profile_text_color = c("333333", "333333", 
            "333333"), profile_use_background_image = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
            TRUE), has_extended_profile = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
            default_profile = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), default_profile_image = c(FALSE, 
            FALSE, FALSE), following = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), follow_request_sent = c(FALSE, 
            FALSE, FALSE), notifications = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("id", 
        "id_str", "name", "screen_name", "location", "description", 
        "url", "entities", "protected", "followers_count", "friends_count", 
        "listed_count", "created_at", "favourites_count", "utc_offset", 
        "time_zone", "geo_enabled", "verified", "statuses_count", 
        "lang", "contributors_enabled", "is_translator", "is_translation_enabled", 
        "profile_background_color", "profile_background_image_url", 
        "profile_background_image_url_https", "profile_background_tile", 
        "profile_image_url", "profile_image_url_https", "profile_link_color", 
        "profile_sidebar_border_color", "profile_sidebar_fill_color", 
        "profile_text_color", "profile_use_background_image", "has_extended_profile", 
        "default_profile", "default_profile_image", "following", 
        "follow_request_sent", "notifications"), row.names = c(NA, 
        3L), class = "data.frame"), geo = c(NA, NA, NA), coordinates = c(NA, 
        NA, NA), place = c(NA, NA, NA), contributors = c(NA, NA, 
        NA), is_quote_status = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), retweet_count = c(0, 
        0, 0), favorite_count = c(0, 0, 0), entities = structure(list(
            hashtags = list(list(), list(), list()), symbols = list(
                list(), list(), list()), user_mentions = list(structure(list(
                screen_name = "esorarad", name = "esorarad", id = 1512420228, 
                id_str = "1512420228", indices = list(c(0, 9))), .Names = c("screen_name", 
            "name", "id", "id_str", "indices"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
                structure(list(screen_name = "esorarad", name = "esorarad", 
                    id = 1512420228, id_str = "1512420228", indices = list(
                      c(0, 9))), .Names = c("screen_name", "name", 
                "id", "id_str", "indices"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
                structure(list(screen_name = "esorarad", name = "esorarad", 
                    id = 1512420228, id_str = "1512420228", indices = list(
                      c(0, 9))), .Names = c("screen_name", "name", 
                "id", "id_str", "indices"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
            urls = list(list(), list(), list())), .Names = c("hashtags", 
        "symbols", "user_mentions", "urls"), row.names = c(NA, 3L
        ), class = "data.frame"), favorited = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
        ), retweeted = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), lang = c("en", "en", 
        "en")), .Names = c("metadata", "created_at", "id", "id_str", 
    "text", "source", "truncated", "in_reply_to_status_id", "in_reply_to_status_id_str", 
    "in_reply_to_user_id", "in_reply_to_user_id_str", "in_reply_to_screen_name", 
    "user", "geo", "coordinates", "place", "contributors", "is_quote_status", 
    "retweet_count", "favorite_count", "entities", "favorited", "retweeted", 
    "lang"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my variable "allMentions".  I want this exact table saved to a CSV.

```
 metadata.iso_language_code metadata.result_type                     created_at           id             id_str
1                         en               recent Thu Oct 22 01:19:44 +0000 2015 6.570034e+17 657003367575760896
2                         en               recent Thu Oct 22 01:15:46 +0000 2015 6.570024e+17 657002373307568129
3                         en               recent Wed Oct 21 20:01:57 +0000 2015 6.569234e+17 656923397985816576
                                                                                                              text
1                                          @esorarad It worked, in case youre curious, since I keep bothering you.
2                                                                                        @esorarad still testing!!
3 @esorarad Hey Dara! Tweeting at you so I can test a program I'm making :P Hopeful game night in the near future!
                                                              source truncated in_reply_to_status_id in_reply_to_status_id_str
1 <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>     FALSE                    NA                        NA
2 <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>     FALSE                    NA                        NA
3 <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>     FALSE                    NA                        NA
  in_reply_to_user_id in_reply_to_user_id_str in_reply_to_screen_name  user.id user.id_str       user.name user.screen_name
1          1512420228              1512420228                esorarad 75328338    75328338 Thomas            uName
2          1512420228              1512420228                esorarad 75328338    75328338 Thomas            uName
3          1512420228              1512420228                esorarad 75328338    75328338 Thomas            uName
    user.location user.description user.url user.urls user.protected user.followers_count user.friends_count user.listed_count
1 Philadelphia PA                        NA      NULL          FALSE                   36                244                 1
2 Philadelphia PA                        NA      NULL          FALSE                   36                244                 1
3 Philadelphia PA                        NA      NULL          FALSE                   36                244                 1
                 user.created_at user.favourites_count user.utc_offset user.time_zone user.geo_enabled user.verified
1 Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009                   121          -18000          Quito            FALSE         FALSE
2 Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009                   121          -18000          Quito            FALSE         FALSE
3 Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009                   121          -18000          Quito            FALSE         FALSE
  user.statuses_count user.lang user.contributors_enabled user.is_translator user.is_translation_enabled user.profile_background_color
1                 616        en                     FALSE              FALSE                       FALSE                        C0DEED
2                 616        en                     FALSE              FALSE                       FALSE                        C0DEED
3                 616        en                     FALSE              FALSE                       FALSE                        C0DEED
                 user.profile_background_image_url           user.profile_background_image_url_https user.profile_background_tile
1 http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png                        FALSE
2 http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png                        FALSE
3 http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png                        FALSE
                                                       user.profile_image_url
1 http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg
2 http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg
3 http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg
                                                  user.profile_image_url_https user.profile_link_color
1 https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg                  0084B4
2 https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg                  0084B4
3 https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg                  0084B4
  user.profile_sidebar_border_color user.profile_sidebar_fill_color user.profile_text_color user.profile_use_background_image
1                            C0DEED                          DDEEF6                  333333                              TRUE
2                            C0DEED                          DDEEF6                  333333                              TRUE
3                            C0DEED                          DDEEF6                  333333                              TRUE
  user.has_extended_profile user.default_profile user.default_profile_image user.following user.follow_request_sent user.notifications
1                     FALSE                 TRUE                      FALSE          FALSE                    FALSE              FALSE
2                     FALSE                 TRUE                      FALSE          FALSE                    FALSE              FALSE
3                     FALSE                 TRUE                      FALSE          FALSE                    FALSE              FALSE
  geo coordinates place contributors is_quote_status retweet_count favorite_count entities.hashtags entities.symbols
1  NA          NA    NA           NA           FALSE             0              0              NULL             NULL
2  NA          NA    NA           NA           FALSE             0              0              NULL             NULL
3  NA          NA    NA           NA           FALSE             0              0              NULL             NULL
                            entities.user_mentions entities.urls favorited retweeted lang
1 esorarad, esorarad, 1512420228, 1512420228, 0, 9          NULL     FALSE     FALSE   en
2 esorarad, esorarad, 1512420228, 1512420228, 0, 9          NULL     FALSE     FALSE   en
3 esorarad, esorarad, 1512420228, 1512420228, 0, 9          NULL     FALSE     FALSE   en
```

Comment: Looks like you have a `data.frame`. Can you check the `str(allMentions)`

Comment: Sure. It says it is.  "> str(allMentions)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ metadata                 :'data.frame':      3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ iso_language_code: chr  "en" "en" "en"
  ..$ result_type      : chr  "recent" "recent" "recent"

Then it lists all my variables : theirType theirValues.

However when I try to write this to a CSV I get "Error in ncol(xj) : object 'xj' not found"

Comment: Can you show the `write.csv` code?  I would use `write.csv(allMentions, file='file.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)`

Comment: Can you try `df1 <- do.call(data.frame, allMentions)` and then `write.csv`

Comment: write.csv(allMentions, paste(fileLocation, Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")) is what I was using.

As per your suggestion tried --> write.csv(allMentions,paste("C:\\Users\\Tom\\Desktop\\NewProgramFile-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep=""), row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
   Got the same Error in ncol(xj): object 'xj' not found error.

Comment: Sure.  After doing the "df1" line you suggested, I tried to write it. I used your "write.csv" line, and got back -->  Error in write.table(x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol, na, dec, as.integer(quote),  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

Comment: Based on the `str`, it looks like  you have a data.frame within a data.fame.  It would have been better to show the `dput` output of that input dataset.  But, try with `do.call` and see if it works (not tested)

Comment: I will provide my actual data frame in the editted comment in just 1 moment.

Editted it in.

Comment: Thanks, so you have some `list` elements, `data.frame` within `data.frame` etc..

Comment: Alright, so then is it impossible to save this json output from Twtiter data as is to a CSV file?

Comment: Have you tried the `jsonlite` package.

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with json as a whole.  I used jsonlite library previously to use toJSON/fromJSON but that's about it.  What parts of the package do you recommend I read up on?

Comment: Can you show the `dput` output of a small part of the dataset for testing? ie. `dput(droplevels(head(allMentions)))`

Comment: Editted in my exact variable. This is my variable "allMentions".  I want this exact table saved to a CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Possibly, somebody will test it.

Comment: Yeah, maybe.  Thanks for your efforts.  I attempted to flatten the file with no luck. I'm just kind of at an impass at the moment on how to save all of this information into a neatly packed CSV.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would be able to capture the nested list structure within a CSV file. If you flatten it you need (external) information to unflatten it. For example `as.matrix(allMentions)` gives the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... I'm not answering your question as I don't think CSV files are the right format for this but here's a JSON version (and I think it preserves the structure for a rainy day).

Save data

```
library(jsonlite)
dput(serializeJSON(allMentions), file="lala.json")
```

Read in data

```
library(jsonlite)
indata <- unserializeJSON(fromJSON("lala.json"))
```

which gives

```
  metadata.iso_language_code metadata.result_type                     created_at
1                         en               recent Thu Oct 22 01:19:44 +0000 2015
2                         en               recent Thu Oct 22 01:15:46 +0000 2015
3                         en               recent Wed Oct 21 20:01:57 +0000 2015
            id             id_str
1 6.570034e+17 657003367575760896
2 6.570024e+17 657002373307568129
3 6.569234e+17 656923397985816576
```

and `str(indata)` yields

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ metadata                 :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ iso_language_code: chr  "en" "en" "en"
  ..$ result_type      : chr  "recent" "recent" "recent"
 $ created_at               : chr  "Thu Oct 22 01:19:44 +0000 2015" "Thu Oct 22 01:15:46 +0000 2015" "Wed Oct 21 20:01:57 +0000 2015"
 $ id                       : num  6.57e+17 6.57e+17 6.57e+17
 $ id_str                   : chr  "657003367575760896" "657002373307568129" "656923397985816576"
 $ text                     : chr  "@esorarad It worked, in case youre curious, since I keep bothering you." "@esorarad still testing!!" "@esorarad Hey Dara! Tweeting at you so I can test a program I'm making :P Hopeful game night in the near future!"
 $ source                   : chr  "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>" "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>" "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>"
 $ truncated                : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ in_reply_to_status_id    : logi  NA NA NA
 $ in_reply_to_status_id_str: logi  NA NA NA
 $ in_reply_to_user_id      : num  1.51e+09 1.51e+09 1.51e+09
 $ in_reply_to_user_id_str  : chr  "1512420228" "1512420228" "1512420228"
 $ in_reply_to_screen_name  : chr  "esorarad" "esorarad" "esorarad"
 $ user                     :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  40 variables:
  ..$ id                                : num  75328338 75328338 75328338
  ..$ id_str                            : chr  "75328338" "75328338" "75328338"
  ..$ name                              : chr  "Thomas" "Thomas" "Thomas"
  ..$ screen_name                       : chr  "uName" "uName" "uName"
  ..$ location                          : chr  "Philadelphia PA" "Philadelphia PA" "Philadelphia PA"
  ..$ description                       : chr  "" "" ""
  ..$ url                               : logi  NA NA NA
  ..$ entities                          :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ description:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. ..$ urls:List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ : list()
  .. .. .. ..$ : list()
  .. .. .. ..$ : list()
  ..$ protected                         : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ followers_count                   : num  36 36 36
  ..$ friends_count                     : num  244 244 244
  ..$ listed_count                      : num  1 1 1
  ..$ created_at                        : chr  "Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009" "Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009" "Fri Sep 18 16:56:20 +0000 2009"
  ..$ favourites_count                  : num  121 121 121
  ..$ utc_offset                        : num  -18000 -18000 -18000
  ..$ time_zone                         : chr  "Quito" "Quito" "Quito"
  ..$ geo_enabled                       : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ verified                          : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ statuses_count                    : num  616 616 616
  ..$ lang                              : chr  "en" "en" "en"
  ..$ contributors_enabled              : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ is_translator                     : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ is_translation_enabled            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ profile_background_color          : chr  "C0DEED" "C0DEED" "C0DEED"
  ..$ profile_background_image_url      : chr  "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png"
  ..$ profile_background_image_url_https: chr  "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png" "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png"
  ..$ profile_background_tile           : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ profile_image_url                 : chr  "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg" "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg" "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg"
  ..$ profile_image_url_https           : chr  "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg" "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg" "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/563789490821410817/vB2dhVj1_normal.jpeg"
  ..$ profile_link_color                : chr  "0084B4" "0084B4" "0084B4"
  ..$ profile_sidebar_border_color      : chr  "C0DEED" "C0DEED" "C0DEED"
  ..$ profile_sidebar_fill_color        : chr  "DDEEF6" "DDEEF6" "DDEEF6"
  ..$ profile_text_color                : chr  "333333" "333333" "333333"
  ..$ profile_use_background_image      : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE
  ..$ has_extended_profile              : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ default_profile                   : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE
  ..$ default_profile_image             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ following                         : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ follow_request_sent               : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
  ..$ notifications                     : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ geo                      : logi  NA NA NA
 $ coordinates              : logi  NA NA NA
 $ place                    : logi  NA NA NA
 $ contributors             : logi  NA NA NA
 $ is_quote_status          : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ retweet_count            : num  0 0 0
 $ favorite_count           : num  0 0 0
 $ entities                 :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ hashtags     :List of 3
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  ..$ symbols      :List of 3
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  ..$ user_mentions:List of 3
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. ..$ screen_name: chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ name       : chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ id         : num 1.51e+09
  .. .. ..$ id_str     : chr "1512420228"
  .. .. ..$ indices    :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ : num  0 9
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. ..$ screen_name: chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ name       : chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ id         : num 1.51e+09
  .. .. ..$ id_str     : chr "1512420228"
  .. .. ..$ indices    :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ : num  0 9
  .. ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. ..$ screen_name: chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ name       : chr "esorarad"
  .. .. ..$ id         : num 1.51e+09
  .. .. ..$ id_str     : chr "1512420228"
  .. .. ..$ indices    :List of 1
  .. .. .. ..$ : num  0 9
  ..$ urls         :List of 3
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
  .. ..$ : list()
 $ favorited                : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ retweeted                : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE
 $ lang                     : chr  "en" "en" "en"
```

Comment: Just curious why you don't think I should be using a CSV?

I want to be able to have all of the information tabulated, and easily accessible.  I just want to be able to do something like...Let's look at $entities for example.  It's a dataframe, with even more data frames inside of it.  Why can't I have a CSV, with a column entities.hashtags, entities.symbols, entitites.user_mentions.screen_name, entities.user_mentions.name, entities.user_mentions.id, etc. ?

Comment: I'm sure it should be possible to flatten it but then you'd need some information to "deflatten it" since you won't be able to distinguish names from structures (eg, are x.x and x.y two separate variable names or two variables from within the same nested structure). That was my comment from above with a requirement for "external information". For example that that cannot occur or you have information on recreating the structure. JSON keeps the exact structure.

Comment: I see.  What if I didn't really plan to ever deflatten it?  Pretty much, my only goal is to be able to easily parse this data working with a lot of other (CSV) data that I already have.  So I'd like to try and keep everything in the same format for consistency.  What would be the best way to flatten this data?  I had tried jsonlite's flatten(allMentions) but it didn't seem to do anything - I still was left with the same data.frame within a data.frame structure.  Is there a pre-existing way to just automatically do this?

Comment: As a small update, I actually think that if I did something like :  individualTweet = unlist( allMentions[i] ) and looped over all values of i, and just printed row by row, I would get what I want.